# Show that $\ S(2n, n) \ ≥ n!$ for all $ n ≥ 1$.

Tags: combinatorics

I have been given the following practice question about Stirling numbers of the second kind:

> Show that $\ S(2n, n)\ ≥ n!$ for all $ n ≥ 1$.

I don't know where to start with this and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: what does S(2n,n) mean in terms of partitions

Comment: The number of partitions of a set of size 2n into n non-empty parts?

Comment: Consider the partitions of a size $2n$ set into parts of size $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints for one possible solution:

- Since $2n/n=2$, some of the partitions of $\{1,\cdots,2n\}$ into $n$-parts are specfically partitions into size-two subsets that look like $\{a,b\}$.
- A factorial $n!$ counts the number of permutations of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$
- The sets $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and $\{n+1,\cdots,2n\}$ have the same size...
- A function $f:X\to Y$ can be treated as a collection of ordered pairs in $X\times Y$